# The designer has given me the PSD. Now, how do I create my android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, psd

My designer has given me the following layout (a little bit changed to protect my business :)

[image]

Now, I am facing a lot of doubts as how I can incorporate every element to my android layout.

1. As you can see, the background has a light noise to it. I tried creating a 9patch from it, but when loading in Android, I completely lost the quality of the imaged. It stretched out weirdly. Should I have one background for the different resolutions (ie. mdpi, hdpi... ) or can this be achieved with 9 patch
2. What to do with the button? I tried saving the button (which in photoshop it is a group) into a new image and saved it as a PNG. When loading in the layout with a ImageButton and trying on my phone, the button is just **too** big. How can I guarantee the size of the button on different type of screens? Will I need different sizes of this button for different resolutions (mdpi... ) and if so, how will I know what is the size of this button for a hdpi resolution, or for a mdpi resolution? Or maybe I should force the width and height of the button to a value like 60dp, but that doesn't sound right to me. I understand I can create a shape and apply it to the background of the button but, what about the Facebook button? I imagine that, in that case, I will need a ImageButton with the PNG as background.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: Repeating tiles did not work for me. So basically had to get the PNG and transform it into 9 patch and use it as a background for the button.
It's working just fine throughout the app.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late as hell but hopefully it will help others.

1) Ask your designer for a repeatable image that you can tile for the background. I don't see any reason why it couldn't be tiled. To tile an image make an xml file of type drawable for each of the generalized dpi folders. Put this code in the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/piece_of_the_background_that_can_be_repeated"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Set the background drawable to this xml file.

2)  Set a 9patch image as the button background and use [this custom textView](http://qwerjk.com/magic-text/) for the text. Use the innerShadow attribute to get the shadow effect your designer shows.